# Kal-el finding Kara's scoutship and the 18 thousand year gap between them

Tags: plot-explanation, man-of-steel, dc-extended-universe

In *Man of Steel* we saw Kal-el finding Kara's scout ship. He finds several pods and one of them is Kara's. In the prequel there were ships to be launched in the void (age of expansion) and one of them had Kara commanding it and that ship crashed on Earth.

But we saw that in the movie that ship was 18,000+ years old, so it was launched 18000+ years ago. But Zor-el and Jor-el are brothers they came from the same father, Zor-el and Jor-el where born around the same time. It's impossible for me to see him 18,000+ years before Krypton's destruction where we saw Jor-el, and at the time of destruction Kal-el was born. Kal-el and Kara are cousins and the age gap is around a few years. Kara's pod was open when she was attacked by Dev-em and when it crashed she got out of the ship, and then 18000+ years had gone by and we saw Kal-el on earth. Also his ship had a Phantom drive which means the time of travel between planets was about a few hours, so he was not launched 18000+ years ago, we know this from when we saw him being launched around the time of destruction.

Can someone please explain this because this whole plot does not make any sense to me? If someone understands why the plot is like that please answer. This has been Baffling me to my extent since I saw the movie and read the prequel comic.

Comment: What prequel are you actually talking about here?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been possible in real life for hypothetical alien ships to travel at almost the speed of flight for 18,000 Earth years and experience strong time dilation so that almost no time elapsed on board?  And if Kara is supposed to have left 18,000 Kryptonian years before Kal-el, a planet in the habitable zone of a red dwarf star might have a year only 6 Earth days long, making 18,000 of those years only  295 Earth years, making the time gap much smaller.

Answer (score 5):

You're absolutely right. The clear implication from the comic (available online [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2b3W.jpg)) is that [Kara Zor-El](http://dccinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kara_Zor-El) (AKA Supergirl) came to Earth in the scoutship that we see in the film, some 18,000 years ago.

There's a few points to note:

- The film universe is not the comic universe. Although the characters are the same, there's no reason to assume that their timelines or ages are the same.
- Kryptonians are essentially immortal. 18,000 years could easily have passed on Krypton between the launch of the scoutships and the launch of the pod carrying the newborn Kal-El.
- At least one of Kara's contemporaries ([Nam-Ek](http://dccinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nam-Ek)) lives long enough to join Zod's forces in the film.